# Как узнать GMT в JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне узнать в JavaScript - GMT, или как сделать его на **GMT+0000** при `new Date();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы узнать, в каком Вы часовом поясе, можно использовать метод `getTimezoneOffset()`:

> **Return Value:** A Number, representing the time difference between UTC and Local Time, in minutes.

Что немного неинтуитивно, это что возвращаемое значение имеет противоположный знак от UTC offset, то есть, для UTC+1 вы получите `-60`.

Если же вы хотите создать объект типа `Date` c UTC, то можно использовать `Date.UTC`:

```
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));
```

Comment: А все же, как мне узнать какой UTC+ у пользователя?

Comment: Используйте `getTimezoneOffset()`: `var curOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60; var utc = "UTC" + (curOffset > 0 ? "-" + curOffset : "+" + (-curOffset));`  И получите, например, `UTC+3` для Москвы.

Comment: Интереснее вопрос о зимнем/летнем времени.  Ведь это повлияет на UTC (например, зимой в Лондоне UTC+0,  а летом UTC+1).  [Вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/check-if-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-for-how-many-hours) хорошее решение.

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю вопрос.  Что нужно вычислить?

Comment: Ну в консоли мне выдает вот такой ответ на  Date(); "Thu Jun 18 2015 00:57:04 GMT+0500 (RTZ 4 (зима))", мне надо вычесть получается 5 часов, чтобы часовой пояс был пол нулям. Как вычесть эти 5 часов из выданной даты?

Comment: А что Вы, собственно, пытаетесь получить в конечном итоге?  Может, просто `new Date().toUTCString()` Вас устроит?  Если нет, то всегда можно просто вычесть (добавить) соответствующие минуты: `var cd = new Date(); cd.setMinutes(cd.getMinutes() + cd.getTimezoneOffset());`

Comment: Я пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы функция Date(); не использовала время с компьютера, а то которое на сервере оно настроено под UTC+0000

Comment: Этого просто так не сделаешь.  Функция Date() запускается на клиентском компе и ничего не знает о сервере.  Если хотите узнать, какое время в UTC - любой из двух вариантов в моем предыдущем комменте подойдет.